# getting class cast exception while storing the content of list into set

Tags: java, hibernate

I have fired the below hibernate query which is fetching the data perfectly but the return type is of List as shown below..

```
public List<Object[]> Extractingc()
    {

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(IDetails.class);
        ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
            proList.add(Projections.property("ter"));  //is of string type
        proList.add(Projections.property("sem"));  //is of string type
        proList.add(Projections.property("tid"));  //is of long type in pojo  *******
                proList.add(Projections.property("def"));  //is of string type
        criteria.setProjection(proList);            
        List<Object[]> settlementIdList =  criteria.list();
        return sst;

    }
```

now the problem comes in java code is that i am putting the result of above method in an an list further in code as shown below...

```
List<Object[]> ioaist = = ioabookandinstrumenthome.Extractingc();
```

now further i have created a set as in set i want to store  the combination of all 4 parameters that is sem+tid+ter+def in the set that is I am doing as shown below...

```
Set<String> st = new HashSet<String>();
for (Object[] arr : ioabookandinstrumenthomelist)
{
s=((String) arr[0]+ (String) arr[1]+ (String) arr[2]+ (String) arr[3]); //*** getting class cast exception
st.add(s);
s=null;
}
```

but I am getting class cast exception as my parameter tid is long type which is not converted in string

Comment: so what's the question again?

Comment: Can you please post your questions properly.

Comment: *2cents:* this-> `ioabookandinstrumenthome` isn't the best way to name anything. this_or thisWouldBeBetter.

Comment: You return `sst`...what is this and where is it declared?  I do a search of `sst` on this page and find only a single reference--where you return it (so where are you modifying it and where are you declaring it as anything?).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't cast longs to Strings. You can however use [String.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28long%29)